# 2003 Ford Escape charging issue

Tags: ford, alternator, charging, escape

So I’ve had alternator issues in the past in my 2003 Ford Escape. Just the other day my battery light came on, I took out the alternator and the battery and my alternator failed a bench test, so I replaced it re wired everything and set it all back up. When I was finished I got it in car tested and it failed again, the mechanic told me it was likely a loose connection (which it was) after replacing the alternator plug and splicing the wires together the alternator still failed a voltage test. So I took out the brand new alternator and they did a bench test with it. They said it failed the test and was likely due to the old wires and shorting it out. So I got a 2nd brand new alternator, a brand new battery and a new plug but even after all of that my escape is still failing voltage tests. Was looking for any advice please and thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this a "brand new" alternator or a rebuilt one? When you replaced the "new" one, was it from the same manufacturer?

Comment: Worth checking the engine earth strap has a good connection and is not frayed.

Comment: It is a brand new alternator and yes it was the same manufacturer.

Comment: Sometimes there can be a batch of a product which goes bad in the manufacturing process. It could be, you've gotten alternators from the same batch, and they were both just bad. It doesn't matter if they were new or rebuilt, can happen either way. You may want to see about getting a replacement other than of the manufacture you have. Realistically, it doesn't matter which way you go (new or rebuilt), both are usually of good quality in most cases.